# How to pass env variable in hive script?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hql script with test.hql
in that i'm having env variable like this in query date='${env:date}'
how can i pass an argument to the hql
if it is hiveconf or hivevar we run script like

```
hive -f --hiveconf date='20220526' test.hql
```

can some one tell how will we pass env variable

```
hive -f --env date='20220526' test.hql
```

i'm not able to pass like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables would be interpreted by the shell, not a query.

```
export DATE='20220526' 
hive -f --hiveconf date="$DATE" test.hql
```

Also, `beeline` should be used rather than deprecated Hive cli

Comment: I'm getting missing  argument for option:f
usage: beeline options

i'm not able to run the job

Comment: I only copied the line provided in your question. `-f` should be put before the filename, not before --hiveconf